# apt-get install not working

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line, apt

`sudo apt-get install <anything>` is not working in my terminal
Whenever i try doing it, it displays the following error message:-

```
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main vim-runtime all 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1
  Could not connect to 111.125.139.199:8105 (111.125.139.199). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main vim amd64 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1
  Unable to connect to 111.125.139.199:8105:
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-runtime_7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_all.deb  Could not connect to 111.125.139.199:8105 (111.125.139.199). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim_7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to 111.125.139.199:8105:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Are you using a hardware firewall?

Comment: i hope not..this is not my personal system, it's official one !

Comment: have you tried following the suggested actions? (...`maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`)

Comment: yes i did, none helped

Comment: @Eliran Malka how to try the latter one.. --fix-missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there's a problem with the archives in the mirror you are using.

Try opening "Update Manager", click "Settings" and on the "Ubuntu software" tab choose a different "Download from" server.

Then check for updates again and then try `apt-get install` again.

Comment: tried doing this>> sudo apt-get install vim
sudo: unable to resolve host l-vverma
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package vim is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'vim' has no installation candidate

Comment: PS:- i don't know ho to format the comments properly.. ctrl+K simply doesn't work while commenting

Comment: please help someone, i am not able to install anything

Comment: Did you try changing the server mirror as I suggested in the answer above?

Comment: yes, i tried the same but it didn't work :/

Comment: please help me!

Comment: to check if the problem is with your configuration, try running ubuntu from a liveUSB or liveDVD and see if the problem is present there too.

Comment: If that works try copying the /etc/apt/sources.list from the live DVD to your system. Then apt-get update.

Comment: replaced the same, still it didn't work :/

Comment: Did the updating process work on the liveDVD?