# Unable to connect to za.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: updates

I've been trying to update my Ubuntu 20.04 server and have been getting this:

```
mike@:~$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not connect to za.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (197.155.77.2). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to za.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2c0f:fe40:8001:10::2). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:2 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to za.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:3 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to za.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:4 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to za.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Reading package lists... Done                          
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to za.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (197.155.77.2). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to za.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2c0f:fe40:8001:10::2). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to za.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to za.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to za.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Does anyone know what's going on? Is it just the South African archive? It's been two days now. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to fetch security undetermined error \[IP: 91.189.91.38 80\] in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305141/failed-to-fetch-security-undetermined-error-ip-91-189-91-38-80-in-ubuntu-20-0)

Comment: Not really, but thanks.I understand that I don't need to use a mirror, but it is usually more efficient. I was just wondering if the South African archive server was down for some reason. It has happened before, for syncing I assume, but it usually doesn't stay down for more than a couple of hours.

Comment: You would know better with `sudo traceroute -T 197.155.77.2`

Comment: The problem is clearly with the mirror. I'll give it another day or two.

Comment: If You Don't Mind Using Other Mirrors In the meantime,  
You can edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to replace `http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` with `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get install not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204602/apt-get-install-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the archive at `za.archive.ubuntu.com` is currently down.

I've resolved this for myself using these two methods:

1. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` as mentioned in the comment by @ByronTaaka.
2. Use [apt-select](https://github.com/jblakeman/apt-select) as described in the article [How to Find Best Ubuntu APT Repository Mirror](https://www.letscloud.io/community/how-to-find-best-ubuntu-apt-repository-mirror).

Using method 2, it modified `/etc/apt/sources.list` and pointed all references to http://ftp.leg.uct.ac.za. I'm based in Cape Town so this works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

za.archive.ubuntu.com is back up. In the interim I stopped using mirrors, but have found a few that had continued to work. among them: mirror.wiru.co.za and ftp.leg.uct.ac.za (as mentioned by Jonathan above).

I have found no explanation for what happened, or why it was down for so long.